# make a private route to async route in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react router v4 for routing in my application. The component, sagas and reducers are loaded asynchronously. How can i now implement private routing and public routing in such case?

Here is the code for routing and loading

```
/**
 * A wrapper component that will lazily render a component after it has been loaded.
 */
class Bundle extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  state = {
    // short for "module" but that's a keyword in js, so "mod"
    mod: null
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.load(this.props);
  }

  /* istanbul ignore next */
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.load !== this.props.load) {
      this.load(nextProps);
    }
  }

  load(props) {
    this.setState({
      mod: null
    });
    props.load(this.context.store, mod => {
      this.setState({
        // handle both es imports and cjs
        mod: mod.default ? mod.default : mod
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const { load, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    return this.state.mod && <this.state.mod {...otherProps} />;
  }
}

const AsyncRoute = ({ load, ...others }) => (
  <Route {...others} render={props => <Bundle load={load} {...props} />} />
);

AsyncRoute.propTypes = {
  computedMatch: React.PropTypes.object,
  path: React.PropTypes.string,
  load: React.PropTypes.func
};

export default AsyncRoute;


// how can i make private route with different layout not a children of App
function Routes({ location }) {
  return (
    <Switch location={location}>
      <AsyncRoute exact path="/" load={loadHomePage} />
      <AsyncRoute exact path="/signup" load={loadSignupPage} />
      <AsyncRoute path="" load={loadNotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
}


export default (store, cb) => {
  const { injectReducer, injectSagas } = getAsyncInjectors(store);
  const importModules = Promise.all([
    import("./reducer"),
    import("./sagas"),
    import("./index")
  ]);

  importModules.then(([reducer, sagas, component]) => {
    injectReducer("signup", reducer.default);
    injectSagas(sagas.default);

    cb(component);
  });

  importModules.catch(errorLoading);
};

const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used `react-router-redux` to sync your history with your redux store, you can create a saga in the main chunk that takes the latest `LOCATION_CHANGE` action type from `react-router-redux` and refresh your authentication (store it in `auth` reducer) by calling some API.

To distinguish between private and public components, you can modify `Bundle` such that it defers from asynchronously loading private chunks until the `auth` state is valid.

Here are some code sketch

**sagas/auth.js**

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux'

function *checkAuth() {
   yield put(authenticateStart())
   // Assuming using some token authentication
   const token = yield select(state => state.auth.token)
   const result = yield call(Api.refreshAuth, token)
   if (result.isAuthenticated) {
      yield put(authenticateSuccess(result.user)
   } else {
      // Need auth
      yield put(authenticateError())
   }
}
// Put this saga on main bundle
function *authSaga() {
    yield* takeLatest(LOCATION_CHANGE, checkAuth)
}
```

**bundle.js**

```
class Bundle extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  state = {
    // short for "module" but that's a keyword in js, so "mod"
    mod: null
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.isProtected && !this.props.isAuthenticated)
       return
    this.load(this.props);
  }

  /* istanbul ignore next */
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Modify similar to above
  }

  load(props) {
    this.setState({
      mod: null
    });
    props.load(this.context.store, mod => {
      this.setState({
        // handle both es imports and cjs
        mod: mod.default ? mod.default : mod
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const { load, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    return this.state.mod && <this.state.mod {...otherProps} />;
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated }))(Bundle)
```

Comment: Can you show a glimpse ? I did not understand fully.